# No Directive annotation found on CustomerService

Tags: angular

The error is pretty direct but I do have an annotation for `CustomerService` and declare it via `Directives`.

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {CustomerModel} from "../components/Customer/CustomerModel"

@Injectable()
export class CustomerService{

    customerList:CustomerModel[] = [
        new CustomerModel("Mr. "),
        new CustomerModel("Miss. "),
        new CustomerModel("Ms. "),
    ];

}
```

Customer.ts

```
export class CustomerModel{

    firstName:String = "";
    lastName:String = "";


    constructor(title:String = ""){

    }

}
```

CustomersComponent.ts

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {CustomerService} from "../../services/CustomerService"
import {CustomerModel} from "./CustomerModel";

@Component({
    selector:'customers',
    template: require('./Customer.html'),

    directives:[
        CustomerService
    ]
})

export class CustomersComponent {

    title:string = "Hello Drew";
    customer:CustomerModel = new CustomerModel();

    constructor(public service:CustomerService){

    }

    onSubmit(){
        this.service.customerList.push(this.customer);
        this.customer = new CustomerModel();
    }
}
```

I added this on github at https://github.com/drewjocham/Angular2TestApp if anyone wants to look at more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a provider, you have to add `CustomerService` to the providers array and not the directives:

```
@Component({
    selector:'customers',
    template: require('./Customer.html'),

    providers:[
        CustomerService
    ]
})
```

But before you proceed any further, I would advise you to update to the latest Release Candidate of Angular2 (RC.6), but that's just an advice :). Thereby, if you have no dependency injection going on in the constructor of your `CustomerService`, then the `@Injectable()` is not necessary

Comment: I used yeoman to generate this project. I wonder why they are not on the latest update. Thank you for the reply.